# Why isn't my button pushing from my app to Apple Maps?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, mapkit

I have a navigation app I am working on which works like a normal maps app, allowing you to search for locations through a search table etc. In the app, the user can create annotations by clicking a result they want from my searchable.

QUESTION: When the user taps an annotation, a pop-up button should appear above it, as I have created it programmatically.  Upon click, it should push the user to the Apple Maps app with the route to the annotation they clicked preloaded in. It's not pushing me there anymore, which is weird because it used to work.  Here's the programmatically created button:

```
extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
            return nil
        }
        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.red
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true
        let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: (CGPoint()), size: smallSquare))
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "car"), for: [])
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getDirections), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        
        pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
        return pinView
    }
}
```

and this is supposed to carry it out (in the class)

```
@objc func getDirections(){
    if let selectedPin = selectedPin {
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPin)
        let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}
```

Could it be something weird with the Objective-C function? This is the code I recently added that potentially could have caused the issue, though I really don't know:

```
func resolveAddress(for averageCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completion: @escaping (MKPlacemark?) -> () ) {

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    let averageLocation = CLLocation(latitude: averageCoordinate.latitude, longitude: averageCoordinate.longitude)
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(averageLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
        guard error == nil,
            let placemark = placemarks?.first
        else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        completion(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark ))
    }
}

@IBAction func middleFinderButton(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let totalLatitude = mapView.annotations.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.coordinate.latitude }
    
    let totalLongitude = mapView.annotations.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.coordinate.longitude }
    
    let averageLatitude = totalLatitude/Double(mapView.annotations.count)
    
    let averageLongitude = totalLongitude/Double(mapView.annotations.count)
    
    let centerPoint = MKPointAnnotation()
    
    centerPoint.coordinate.latitude = averageLatitude
    centerPoint.coordinate.longitude = averageLongitude
    
    
    mapView.addAnnotation(centerPoint)
    
    resolveAddress(for: centerPoint.coordinate) { placemark in
        if let placemark = placemark {
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(placemark)
        } else {
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(centerPoint)
        }
    }

    print(totalLatitude)
    print(totalLongitude)
    print(averageLatitude)
    print(averageLongitude)
    print(centerPoint.coordinate)
}
```

github link: github.com/derekvandermark/VHNavigationAppOfficial-v-0.93

Anyone have an idea why this button isn't working and pushing the app to maps with a preset route? Could it be a glitch with the simulator? (It used to work so I doubt it...)

Comment: Can you just rephrase your question? Your title is unclear. Your first paragraph has some noise in it. The formatting/indentation of the first snippet is off. Copy/past from Xcode and then select all that code and do `cmmd + K`.

Comment: @Honey Hopefully this is more clear now, I cleaned up the question and code. Thanks.

Comment: So what actually happens when you tap your button?

Comment: @matt Nothing.  It used to just push me to apple maps, now I click it and nothing happens.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint to see if your code is even being called?

Comment: By the way your code for dequeuing an annotation view is totally wrong. Irrelevant to the question though.

Answer (score 0):

to push the user to the maps app you could try this:

```
func openMap(lat: String, lng: String){

    let lat1 : NSString = lat as NSString
    let lng1 : NSString = lng as NSString

    let latitude:CLLocationDegrees =  lat1.doubleValue
    let longitude:CLLocationDegrees =  lng1.doubleValue

    let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, latitudinalMeters: regionDistance, longitudinalMeters: regionDistance)
    let options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
    ]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
}
```

Comment: Don't suggest bridging to `NSString` to create a `Double`. The proper Swift syntax is `let latitude = Double(lat) ?? 0.0` or even  `let latitude = CLLocationDegrees(lat) ?? 0.0`

Comment: @vadian  So when I use Jonas's method I get this error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MKCoordinateRegion' with an argument list of type '(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D etc...' on the 'let regionspan =' line.  How do I fix that? And vadian when I change it from a string I get these errors: 'Definition conflicts with previous value' and I changed the parameters to 'Double' and have the same kind of error.  Also, Are you suggesting I put this as a function in replacement of my getDirections function? If not where are you suggesting that I implement it?  Any idea how to fix? Thanks!